# How to use get and set?

Tags: c#

I have 4 elements:

- A class EmailGT.cs (for the get and set thing)
- A class Email.cs (to actually send the email)
- Two other Windows Forms to the user press the button and send the email

I wanted to use get and set to define the message and the person who is going to recieve the email.

I've done this:

```
 class EmailGT
{
    private string _mensagem = string.Empty;
    private string _destinatario = string.Empty;

    public string mensagem
    {
        get { return _mensagem; }
        set { _mensagem = value; }
    }

    public string destinatario
    {
        get { return _destinatario; }
        set { _destinatario = value; }
    }

}
}
```

In the Email.cs I have this (I didn't post the whole code since it wouldn't be necessary):

```
 class Email
{
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        EmailGT x = new EmailGT();
        string destinatario = x.destinatario;
        string mensagem = x.mensagem;
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(destinatario);
        message.Subject = "something";
        message.Body = mensagem;
```

And in the Windows Forms (both) I have this:

```
  EmailGT x = new EmailGT();
  Email z = new Email();
  x.mensagem = "teste 2";
  x.destinatario = "my email";
  z.SendEmail();
```

However, both fields go empty on the Email.cs. I guess I didn't really understand how to use this. Can somebody say what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The default value for a string is an empty string. You don't have to explicitly define this, nor do you have to create a backing field in your case. `public string mensagem {get; set;}` is just fine.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I tried those on the first place, but I thought that it would work if I switched to the current code. I was wrong :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EmailGT x` in `SendEmail` has nothing to do with the `EmailGT x` on which you're setting properties. Perhaps you want to change `SendEmail` to accept an `EmailGT` as a parameter:

```
class Email
{
    public void SendEmail(EmailGT x)
    {
        string destinatario = x.destinatario;
        string mensagem = x.mensagem;
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(destinatario);
        message.Subject = "something";
        message.Body = mensagem;
        // snip
    }
}
```

then you'd *pass* the `EmailGT` to `SendEmail`:

```
EmailGT x = new EmailGT();
x.mensagem = "teste 2";
x.destinatario = "my email";

Email z = new Email();
z.SendEmail(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `SendEmail` method declaration to take `EmailGT` instance as a parameter, and use that instance within the method, instead of creating local variable.

```
public void SendEmail(EmailGT x)
{
    string destinatario = x.destinatario;
    string mensagem = x.mensagem;
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(destinatario);
    message.Subject = "something";
    message.Body = mensagem;
}
```

And usage:

```
EmailGT x = new EmailGT();
x.mensagem = "teste 2";
x.destinatario = "my email";

Email z = new Email();
z.SendEmail(x);
```

Comment: your awnser is right too, but stackoverflow didn't let me choose two awnsers right. I had to choose one, forgive me :(